# Erro no assembly do mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I am new to C# and MySQL and I have a little problem. I have an application connected to MySQL, and recently appeared the following error:

```
Could not load the assembly 'version = 6.8.3 Mysql.Data culture = neutral PublicKeyToken = ...
```

I already updated the provider and the Workbench, despite using the xampp, but to no avail. Can someone help me?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site works, for better or worse, in English.  It is not clear why a question which seems to mention C# and MySQL is tagged C, either.  Please translate your question (maybe using Google translate) and post that (maybe along with the original).  Since Google thinks it is Portugese, you should post on http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ and include the correct tags.

Comment: This question belongs on http://pt.stackoverflow.com/, the Portugese version of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the MySql .net connector.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: Thanks Gusman, was it.